# How to package MEAN stack application as docker container with nginx?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, mean-stack

I've made an app using Angular, NestJS (Node.js) and MongoDB and I'm wondering how to easily turn it into a simple docker container, which will contain nginx sever for serving the frontend app and reverse proxy for the backend + the MongoDB. Also it would be cool if there was option for automatic Let's encrypt cert renewal etc.

Is there some pre-made package/template I could just clone, replace the app files and immediately just run? If not, I'd appreciate at least link to some guide on how to build such container myself - It's probably not super hard, but I've never really built anything with Docker (I do have some basic knowledge how it works) and my nginx experience is also very limited...

The expected result should be all-in-one docker app that I can easily provide to anyone, so they can just easily run it with something like docker run -p 80:80 image.

Comment: I'd pretty much always expect this to be three containers, FWIW.  You might be able to adopt one of [Docker's official Javascript sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/javascript/).  As a rule, though, asking for a pointer to an off-site tutorial or prebuilt solution is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow; also see the [help/on-topic].